# Display a border or shape in ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I have an Activity with a ListView, I want each item of the ListView to have a right border or a shape (for example a small circle) inside it that changes color based on a value in the ListView adapter. How can I do this?

I didn't currently create a CustomAdapter for the ListView, but I used a SimpleAdapter which now only displays a list of strings.

Comment: For the effect you desire, you'll need to create a custom adapter only